# Boolean value don't change

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms

I am setting a value to true or false depending on the DetailPage right away in the constructor.

the value (codebehind):

```
bool _mtde = false;

    public bool mTDE
    {
        get => _mtde;
        set
        {
            _mtde = value;
            PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(nameof(mTDE)));
        }
    }
```

the constructors of both DetailPages:

```
public mTDE ()
    {
        InitializeComponent ();
        AddTankerfassungViewModel.tankerfassung.mTDE = true;
    }
```

and:

```
public TDE ()
    {
        InitializeComponent ();
        AddTankerfassungViewModel.tankerfassung.mTDE = false;
    }
```

When `mTDE` is `true` there is an additional information in the E-Mail (codebehind).

```
public void SendData()
    {
        var mTDEText = "";
        if (mTDE)
        {
            mTDEText = "processed manually ";
        }
        .
        .
        .
    }
```

I debugged with breakpoints, searched for all references: nothing. I have no idea why this variable stays on `false`. The breakpoint is hit when I am clicking on the mTDE ContentPage over the MasterDetailPage.

Comment: so you call the constructor of `mTDE` then you call the method `AddTankerfassungViewModel.tankerfassung.SendData()` do I follow correctly? and then you encounter in `SendData` that `if (mTDE)` is evaluated to `false` ? When exactly do you call `SendData()`?

Comment: The method `SendData()` is called trough a Command Binding in my XAML Code. It is like I have 5 entries and when it's all validated the data shall be sent via E-Mail. `SendData()` just containing the E-Mail function. Is the ContentPage completely newly initialized when I am clicking it on the MasterDetailPage? Maybe scenario is caused by the order of pages initialized?

Comment: "Maybe scenario is caused by the order of pages initialized? " sounds reasonable, up to now there is not enough information in your post to reproduce your problem. May be it helps to remove all other pages but one, namely `mTDE` and then you should see weather the variable is set to true. Then you can add the rest of the pages one by one and check each time what happens with the variable

Comment: throw a debug.Writeline in your setter, then monitor the console to see the actual sequence of value changes as your app runs

Comment: Uploaded a screenshot. Value is changing successfully to true and false but in SendData() it seems that it stays on its first state. Breakpoint is hitting the getter as well so this can't be the reason... https://imgur.com/a/6x9PD

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was the "outsourcing" `SendData()`. I created a new class and called it in my ViewModel `SendCommand`.

```
namespace TDE
{
class Email
{
    public static void SendData()
    {
        var mTDEText = "";
        if (AddTankerfassungViewModel.tankerfassung.mTDE)
        {
            mTDEText = "MANUELL ERFASST: ";
        };
        .
        .
        .
    }
}
}
```

And in my ViewModel I called it like this.

```
Email.SendEmail();
```

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

What you should probably do is something like a state changer method that you can call

```
public static bool InvertStates(bool boolThatYouWantToInvert){
    return !boolThatYouWantToInvert;
}
```

Then you can use it like this

```
AddTankerfassungViewModel.tankerfassung.mTDE = InvertStates(AddTankerfassungViewModel.tankerfassung.mTDE)
```

Please note that AddTankerfassungViewModel.tankerfassung.mTDE should be initialized when you declare it and to pay attention the initial value that you want to pass on your first DetailPage

Comment: I set the initial value to `true` because I start with TDE (where I want the value to be false. The value always stays now on true.

Comment: @paulvoelker sounds reasonable ... as the opposite of constant false should be likely a constant true ;)